# About Batch files (Programming)

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I'm programming a batch file that
verifies one by one .txt files in a directory,
if a file is duplicated then this duplicade file
is moved to another directory.
Can anyone tell me if do exists a way more
fast than doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, do you have a little sample (batch) about how and what you want to to? Mhm ... and basically I would also recommend you to use a more powerfull script language than batch for doing file-operation stuffs. With other programming languages like python, ruby, powershell, ... the challenge of handling files is much easier.

Comment: If you only check "a" (one) directory, there will be no duplicate file names.

Comment: You couldn't have duplicate files, file names in the same folder have to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you meant that you want to compare the contents of the text files, and not the names:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (*.txt) do for %%y in (*.txt) do (
  if "%%~x" neq "%%~y" (
    echo n | comp "%%~x" "%%~y"
    if !errorlecel!==0 (
      echo Duplicat found.
      set newDir=%%~nx_Duplicate
      if not exist "!newDir!" md "!newDir!"
      move "%%~y" "!newDir!"
    )
  )
)
```

The above code will search for duplicates of each file and put them in a directory named something like FILENAME_Duplicate. So if it compares `thisfile.txt` to `thatfile.txt` and finds they are duplicates, it will move `thatfile.txt` into a directory called `thisfile_Duplicate`.

Answer (score 1):

Create checksums of all files with md5sum (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) and compare checksums instead of files. It'll be a lot faster.